# Where is the FBSDKSettings.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true) method?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

I can't find the FBSDKSettings class in the newest Facebook SDK version which is on CocoaPods. Can you help?

Answer (score 12):

It has been renamed like this:

```
Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true
```

It is located into Pods/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKSettings.h file.

Comment: you can also add the plist entry from themenance response above to your info.plist if you want Facebook to turn this off automatically.

Answer (score 11):

@Bogy 's answer

> `Settings.isAutoLogAppEventsEnabled = true`

resolves the compilation issue you will get using `FBSDKSettings.setAutoLogAppEventsEnabled(true)` but there is still a warning logged:

```
<Warning>: Please set a value for FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled. Set the flag to TRUE if you want to collect app install, app launch and in-app purchase events automatically. 
To request user consent before collecting data, set the flag value to FALSE, then change to TRUE once user consent is received. 
Learn more: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios#disable-auto-events.
```

Only adding this to my projects `.plist` file helped me

```
<key>FacebookAutoLogAppEventsEnabled</key>
<true/>
```